# how to get the following data from a string

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am using C#

I got a string which looks something like this :

```
myString = "User1:John&User2:Bob'More text"
```

I used

```
var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myString);
```

and then i use `parsed["User1"]` and `parsed["User2"]` to get the data.

My problem is that `parsed["User2"]` returns me not only the name but also everything that comes after it.

I thought maybe to then seperate by the char `'`
But i not sure how to do it since it has a specific behaviour in Visual studio.

I thought about something like this?

```
private static string seperateStringByChar(string text)
{
    int indexOfChar = text.IndexOf(');
    if (indexOfChar > 0)
    {
        return text.Substring(0, indexOfChar);
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: And what was the problem about your attempt? How did you use the return of that method?

Comment: And? did the thing you though work?

Comment: Use `if (s.IndexOf("'") > -1) { return text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf("'")); } else { return string.Empty; }`

Comment: regex might be more useful as User2:Bob*'More text"* would be treated as a User2 value if you using ParseQueryString

Comment: My problem is that i cant use '    
Is there a way to decorate it somehow to be able to use it? 
Since visual studio uses it for writting text inside so i cant put it inside a function the way i do.

Comment: Why use a method to parse a string that is not in the correct format for that method? The separator is the = char not the colon :

Comment: You should put a backslash ( \ ) before it. As it is the escape character https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me as Wiktor suggested.

`if (s.IndexOf("'") > -1) { return text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf("'")); } else { return string.Empty; }`

Comment: Or even https://ideone.com/82GbCl.

Answer (score 0):

A clean way of doing it is by splitting the string besides the index of the `'` and then getting the substring.

```
var splittedText = text.Split('\'');
```

Then you can separate it further. e.g

```
var splittedText2 = splittedtText[0].Split('\&');
var User1 = splittedText2[0].Split(':')[1];
var User2 = splittedText2[1].Split(':')[1];
```

Let's sum up the splitting.

```
var users=myString.Split('\'');
var john = users.Split('&')[0].Split(':')[1];
var bob = users.Split('&')[1].Split(':')[1];
```